# How to add literal code lines in manual page?

Tags: formatting, manpage, groff

I'd like to embed a block of code like this:

```
foreach my $n (1..10) {
    print "$n\n";
}
```

in a groff 'man' document and not have it reformat it into a single line. I'd like to suppress all formatting, and not have groff recognize and process any special characters. This would be like the `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags in HTML. Is this possible to do in groff?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off fill-mode with the `.nf` request, and turn off escape processing with `.eo`; they are correspondingly restored with `.fi` and `.ec`.  groff will process these correctly, but it is possible that some alternate man-page formatters will not.

Example:

```
.TH "Manpage Test" SO
.SH NAME
Manpage test \- test manpage formatting
.SH DETAILS
Here is the example.

.RS
.nf
.eo
foreach my $n (1..10) {
    print "$n\n";
}
.ec
.fi
.RE

.P
And there you have the example.
The code snippet should be rendered as "pre-formatted", and 
following text should be back to filled/adjusted.

.SH AUTHOR
Evil Otto
```

Renders as:

```
Manpage Test(SO)                                              Manpage Test(SO)

NAME
       Manpage test - test manpage formatting

DETAILS
       Here is the example.

              foreach my $n (1..10) {
                  print "$n\n";
              }

       And there you have the example.  The code snippet should be rendered as
       "pre-formatted", and following text should be back to  filled/adjusted.

AUTHOR
       Evil Otto

                                                              Manpage Test(SO)
```

Comment: Maybe the OP should accept this answer (to increase his score, also).

Answer (score 1):

Few now remember that originally man pages were typeset for printing and not only terminal viewing.   It's still possible by outputting postscript (`man -Tps`) or better dvi intermediate:

```
man -Tdvi ... > /tmp/man.dvi && dvipdfmx /tmp/man.dvi -o /tmp/man.pdf && xdg-open /tmp/man.pdf
```

and it's a somewhat good test for "semantic correctness" of formatting that otherwise looks same on terminal.

evil otto's answer is a good start but keeps the regular variable-width font:
[image: dvi rendering with .RS .nf .eo]

---

You probably want a monospaced Courier font:

[image: dvi rendering with .RS .EX .eo]

```
.RS
.ft CR
.nf
.eo
foreach my $n (1..10) {
    print "$n\n";
}
.ec
.fi
.ft R
.RE
```

which can be shortened with `.EX`..`.EE` macro for typesetting examples (plus, it saves and restores previous font family which is cleaner than hardcoding `.ft R`):

```
.RS
.EX
.eo
foreach my $n (1..10) {
    print "$n\n";
}
.ec
.EE
.RE
```

`.EX` is an "extension", no idea what that means for its portability

[groff documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/groff/manual/html_node/Optional-man-extensions.html#index-_002eEX) claims `.EX` takes an optional indent parameter (which could replace the `.RS`...`.RE`) but it didn't work for me (and I don't see any such logic in [the implementation](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/groff.git/tree/tmac/an-ext.tmac?h=1.22.4#n182)).

Comment: with dvi output `.EX` macro you may give you `can't find font 'CR' for a dvi-device` warning due to CW -> CR remapping, but typesetting still works; IIUC [the fix](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?59522) was to move the warning logic so it's not confused by remapping